# Exchange Web Services: Unsubscribe from Events

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I was playing around with stream notifications using EWS in Exchange. Accordingly, I have created some subscriptions, but I have I forgot to save the subscription id.

If I try to create a new subscription, I receive the following error message:
**You have exceeded the available subscriptions for your account.  Remove unnecessary subscriptions and try your request**

The procedure to unsubscribe from stream notifications is described here: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/unsubscribe-operation?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
Unfortunately, the request requires a subscription id which I do not have.

How can I unsubscribe existing stream notifications without the subscription id? Or how can I search for existing subscriptions?¨

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience has been that eventually subscriptions die out, but I can't tell from your post what the time frame involved is.  E.g. if you subscribe but then stop making OpenStreaminConnection on that sub, Exchange should realize after some time (the timeout interval perhaps?) that this is a dead subscription.

The other consideration is to look into using impersonation against the mailbox you're subscribing to.  Again, not clear from your post whether this is just your own mailbox or multiple others.

Comment: You are right, subscriptions seem to to die out. In my example, I was able to make a new subscriptions after some days. Thank you!